# Why for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) and for(int i=0; i<10; i++) return the same?

Tags: c++

Why

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

and

```
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

return the same:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

I was expecting the pre-increment to return:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Since it increments it self before return, right?

Comment: you can init i=1 for getting your result.

Comment: What is the basis for your expectation that they should be different?

Comment: I don't think this question worth the down vote, although the answer is obvious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A `for` loop like

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
```

is basically the same as the following:

```
{
    int i = 0;  // For loop initializer
    while (i < 10)  // For loop condition (and the actual loop)
    {
        std::cout << i << std::endl;  // For loop body
        i++;  // For loop post-expression
    }
}
```

Now changing the loop "post-expression" `i++` to `++i` will not make any difference, since its result is really thrown away, and it's performed at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

For `i++`, add 1 to `i` and return the original value; For `++i`, add 1 to `i` and return the new value. But you don't use the return value of them at all.

If you print out the returned value you might get what you want:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; )
    std::cout << (i++) << std::endl;  // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

for(int i=0; i<10; )
    std::cout << (++i) << std::endl;  // 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: Please note that code like this is regarded as poor practice. The canonical way of writing the latter loop is `for(int i=0; i<10; ++i) std::cout << (i+1) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 1):

Pre-increment `++i` or `i++` only matters when these operators are mixed with other things is the same expression. This is not the case here, the 3rd clause of a for loop is an expression of its own, which is executed by itself. The side effect of updating the value is always sequenced before the next lap in the loop starts.

Please note that it is regarded as bad practice to mix the `++` operators with other things in the same expression, since these operators come with a side effect.

Comment: I would like to know which kinds of things should be mixed with them to make one or the other behavior?